# A PostgreSQL function with loose return data type

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql, entity-attribute-value

Here is the main table with data:

```
CREATE TABLE my_report
(
  id               serial                      NOT NULL primary key,
  report_timestamp timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  value_id         integer                     NOT NULL,
  text_value       character varying(255),
  numeric_value    double precision,
  bool_value       boolean,
  dt_value         timestamp with time zone,
  CONSTRAINT my_report_fkey_valdef FOREIGN KEY (value_id)
      REFERENCES public.my_value_defs (value_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
```

It contains several columns for each value because values can be of different data types.

Which column will be taken depends on 'data_type' column of second table linked with `value_id` foreign key:

```
CREATE TABLE my_value_defs
(
  value_id     serial                NOT NULL primary key,
  value_name   character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  data_type    integer               NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT my_value_defs_pkey PRIMARY KEY (value_id),
  CONSTRAINT my_value_defs_value_name_key UNIQUE (value_name)
);
```

Now I am trying to shorten a huge SQL query by creating a function which can return either `text_value` or `numeric_value` or `bool_value` or `dt_value`, but found that I must explicitly define returned data type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.rep_dta_val(
    val_id integer,
    dt timestamp with time zone,
    timeout integer)
  RETURNS timestamp with time zone AS -- ********** HERE **********
$BODY$SELECT
   r.dt_value
FROM
   my_report r
WHERE
   r.value_id = val_id
   AND r.report_timestamp BETWEEN
      dt - make_interval(secs := timeout)
      AND dt
ORDER BY
   r.report_timestamp desc
LIMIT 1;$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

This function is not complete yet, so please do not complain about it here.

I do not like to convert everything to text. Data types should be kept.

When it is impossible to create a function with variable output data type, then I have to generate a whole SQL query of full length in my application like this:

```
SELECT
(SELECT r.text_value    as acc_right     FROM my_report r WHERE r.value_id =  3 AND r.report_timestamp BETWEEN now() - INTERVAL '60 seconds' AND now() ORDER BY r.report_timestamp desc LIMIT 1),
(SELECT r.numeric_value as h_angle       FROM my_report r WHERE r.value_id =  4 AND r.report_timestamp BETWEEN now() - INTERVAL '60 seconds' AND now() ORDER BY r.report_timestamp desc LIMIT 1),
(SELECT r.text_value    as vol_flow      FROM my_report r WHERE r.value_id = 25 AND r.report_timestamp BETWEEN now() - INTERVAL '60 seconds' AND now() ORDER BY r.report_timestamp desc LIMIT 1),
(SELECT r.numeric_value as draft_mid     FROM my_report r WHERE r.value_id = 57 AND r.report_timestamp BETWEEN now() - INTERVAL '60 seconds' AND now() ORDER BY r.report_timestamp desc LIMIT 1),
(SELECT r.dt_value      as eta_timestamp FROM my_report r WHERE r.value_id = 58 AND r.report_timestamp BETWEEN now() - INTERVAL '60 seconds' AND now() ORDER BY r.report_timestamp desc LIMIT 1);
```

The above mentioned query does exactly that I need, but is simply too long, so I created several functions, one for each data type, and use them like this:

```
SELECT
rep_txt_val( 3, now(), 60) as acc_right,
rep_num_val( 4, now(), 60) as h_angle,
rep_txt_val(25, now(), 60) as vol_flow,
rep_num_val(57, now(), 60) as draft_mid,
rep_dta_val(58, now(), 60) as eta_timestamp;
```

Now I would like to have an universal function for all data types.

**P.S. Why using [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)?**

Because it was formerly a conventional table and THAT was nightmare because columns needed to be automatically created from time to time. Sometimes a conventional user hasn't permissions to execute DDL commands.

I have a fully dynamic configurable software, and amount of values that need to be saved to the table depends on configuration file of this software. I've chosen this model in order to simplify database maintenance and data transfer between systems.

In addition I could say that various values should be saved in their own intervals.

So, I won't give up [EAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model), because it already works more effectively than the former conventional table.

There is no need to represent this vertical structure as horizontal data rows except producing an export for legacy systems. And this is exactly the topic of my question.

Comment: Most of the types are convertible to and from text. Return text and cast to type?

Comment: The design (anti) pattern that you are using is known as ["Entity Attribute Value"](https://mikesmithers.wordpress.com/2013/12/22/the-anti-pattern-eavil-database-design/) and while it looks simple it becomes a nightmare when you need to do reporting or any other non-trivial queries on it. Some people even refer to it as a "write-only-pattern" because it's so hard to do queries on it.

Comment: By returning text your final SQL might look like: SELECT
rep_gen_val( 3, now(), 60) as acc_right,
CAST(rep_gen_val( 4, now(), 60) AS decimal) as h_angle,
rep_gen_val(25, now(), 60) as vol_flow,
CAST(rep_gen_val(57, now(), 60) AS decimal) as draft_mid,
CAST(rep_gen_val(58, now(), 60) AS TIMESTAMP) as eta_timestamp; HOWEVER, your data design looks like needing to be redesigned from scratch, no?

Comment: This model is a nightmare, give it up while there's still time.

Comment: By making the storage of arbitrary values easier ("generic"), you made querying them harder. Every solution has its downsides. The downside of the EAV approach is that you can't query it in a structured way because you don't really know what exactly you stored.

Comment: Nowadays people usually use a JSON column to "extend" a table with "dynamic attributes". You still lose proper data type checking, but at least querying is  a lot easier and more efficient than with the EAV approach. See e.g. here: http://coussej.github.io/2016/01/14/Replacing-EAV-with-JSONB-in-PostgreSQL/

Answer (score 4):

Use a [polymorphic function,](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC) example:

```
create or replace function func(anyelement)
returns anyelement language plpgsql as $$
begin
    raise notice '%', pg_typeof($1)::text;
    case pg_typeof($1)::text
        when 'text' then return 'some text';
        when 'numeric' then return 1.23;
        when 'timestamp without time zone' then return now();
        else return $1;
    end case;
end $$;

select func(null::text), func(null::numeric), func(null::timestamp)

NOTICE:  text
NOTICE:  numeric
NOTICE:  timestamp without time zone

   func    | func |            func            
-----------+------+----------------------------
 some text | 1.23 | 2018-10-02 14:51:51.407031
(1 row)
```

Note that you have to use `anyelement` as an argument to determine returning type.